# How to get X Y coordinates for raspberry pi and python?

Tags: python, coordinates, raspberry-pi3

I will work on a project it required to get the raspberry pi coordinates (X, Y)

But the problem is: the work will be indoor and will have at least 3-4 raspberry pi devices and I need their coordinates.

This image will show it:

[image: Click]

This is an assumption of a squared room, and the numbers are the devices

I need an idea to have their coordinates (indoor) even if they are moving like robots.

My programming language is python.

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/schollz/find; do you need absolute or relative coordinates ?

Comment: http://www.robotshop.com/en/indoor-navigation-positioning-system-433mhz-kit.html

Comment: @Moritz I need the absolute coordinates, I just knew about this technology, does it require any hardware?, for the other hardware it is too expensive while I need to have more than a place to get coordinates from, thank you